# Read & display a word document

Tags: javascript, php, html, ms-word

Is it possible to **READ** a Microsoft Word document's data/contents and display them in a web page? 
If yes, then how to:

- display a particular page or table in the document
- display a particular area or content in the document.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord appears to have the ability to read and write certain Office formats?